# Ubuntu server File copy detect

Tags: security

I have a customer who has experienced data file theft (copied filed)
is there software or a way to detect this copying of multiple files

Or do i have to write something?

Comment: How did they see that the file was copied?

Comment: I caught the user red handed "by accident" in walking past the user.

Comment: oh lucky catch then :D I have seen tools like "iwatch" BUT that does not track "copy" (a copy does not edit the file itself and all those tracking tools focus on changes...).

Comment: I figured the system knows when a file is accessed (read) if one could right code to detect if a user accesses more than like 20 files in a period of say 5 minutes it will lock the user account and alert admin!

Comment: doubt it. Easiest method: I would alias the "cp" command and add a mail command so you get a mail when a file is copied.

Comment: You could cobble something together with the `stat` command, which keeps track of when a file was last accessed. You could enter all this stat information into a database and refresh that every 5 minutes. However, that wouldn't tell you *who* had accessed that file.

Comment: Pity I would have thought there would be some security features out there or from ubuntu grrrr